# how to freeze the datagrid column in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

freeze the first two column but if I want to freeze the column dynamically like 3rd or 4th one how I could do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with variable `FrozenColumnCount` which will set the number of leftmost columns in the grid that are frozen

However if you want to freeze only say the third column, then I think you need to write a custom control. In a datagrid only the leftmost columns can be frozen.