# How to implement a horizontal scrollbar only for a subset of columns in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Example: We have many columns and only want to scroll horizontally for the second column till last column.

```
| Name | Mail | Status | Location | ... many other columns ...
| Jon  | ...  | ...    | ...      | ...
```

Now we would like to 'fix' column `Name` and have a horizontal scrollbar beginning with column `Mail` ending at the last column.

```
| Name | Mail | Status | Location | ... many other columns ...
| Jon  | ...  | ...    | ...      | ...
       |<---  scrollbar here                              --->|
```

Is it possible to implement such a behavior with WPF?

Comment: I know there was the ability to freeze columns in the WPF Toolkit version of the DataGrid, but I'm not sure if it was implemented in MSDN's DataGrid. A quick google search of "WPF DataGrid Frozen Column" returns [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9890361/302677), but I'm not sure if that question is specific to the WPF ToolKit version of the datagrid or not (That property was available on WPF Toolkit). If that doesn't exist in MSDN's `DataGrid`, you'll probably have to implement some custom behavior.

Comment: @Rachel Perfect! I was missing the keyword frozen to start an appropriate search. In MSDN's DataGrid there is still the property FrozenColumnCount which fixes the first n columns and enables scrolling for the last ones. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! (If you post this as an answer, you'll get the accepted check from me)

Comment: Sure, its posted as an answer :) I didn't post it originally since I didn't know if that was a valid property on the DataGrid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [FrozenColumnCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `DataGrid` to specify the number of columns starting from the left that you want to "freeze" in place.

If you want to freeze any other columns that aren't the left-most ones though, you'll probably need to implement a custom behavior. :)